# I'm not able to change the all colors to back color in Visio drawing

Tags: microsoft-visio

i tried so many things to change all the colors to black color and make blank floor plan and nothing is helped me to make the floor plan blank will only includes the drawing with black colo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvkAf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JDPN.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community all i need to apply the black color to the drawing, i posted an example phone.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xQvovlynpqs Have you tried this?